# Absolute convergence of $\sin(n)/(n^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}}$$

is either absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent.

Note that $$\sin(n) \in [-1,1] \text { for} 
\left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}} \right|$$

is bound between $ 0 \text { and }1$.
So we have
$$0\leq \frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{{n}^{2}}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{{n}^{2}}=0 $$
and since
$$\frac{\sin(n)}{{n^{2}}}$$
is bounded between 0 and 0, it converges. 
I haven't proved the non-absolute of the series but I'd like to know if I'm in the right direction.

Edit:
Dam what is going wrong with LaTeX. I don't know how I got into this mess.

Comment: If the series is absolutely convergent, it is also convergent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may prove the **absolute convergence** of the series by writing
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left|\frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{{n}^{2}}
$$ thus your series is **convergent**.

Comment: What about going down the route of using the squeeze theorem? ( just trying to explore different techniques)
It seems that the term of the series a_n is bounded between 0 and 0 and thus has to tend towards zero.

Comment: @user: The terms of the series can tend to $0$ even if the series is divergent. The harmonic series is like this. You can not prove convergence by just showing that the terms tend to $0$.

Comment: And if by the absolute convergence test the series diverges?
Would I then have to determine if the series diverges or convergences? If it converges, then the series is conditionally convergent?

Comment: @user: If a series absolutely diverges, then it might either converge or diverge.

Answer (score 1):

A real or complex series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is said to converge absolutely if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left|a_n\right| = l $ for some $l\in \mathbb{R}$.

Observe that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left|\frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}}\right|\le \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{{n}^{2}}$. But we know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{{n}^{2}}$  is convergent. Therefore by the comparison test $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}}$ is convergent absolutely. That is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sin(n)}{{n}^{2}}$ is convergent.