# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(1/n^2)(\sin(n))^3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(1/n^2)(\sin(n))^3$$

As far as what we have learned are following:

1. **-comparison test**
2. **-limit comparison test**
3. **-alternating series test**
4. **-ratio test**
5. **-root test**

**Firstly**, the limit of the sequence $\sin(1/n^2)(\sin(n))^3$ is convergent and $0$.

**Secondly**, Root test is very scrambled, thus I have tried ratio test.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin(\frac1{(n+1)^2})(\sin(n+1))^3}{\sin(\frac1{n^2})(\sin(n))^3}\tilde =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(\sin(1)\cos(n)+\sin(n)\cos(1))^3}{\sin^3(n)}\\=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin(1)\cos(n)}{sin(n)}+\cos(1)\right)^3$$

the result is indeterminate.

**Thirdly**, I back to stard and start to try compare it with $1/x^m$ kind of expressions. $$\sin(\frac1{n^2})(\sin(n))^3<\dfrac1{n^{2}}$$ seems to hold for big numbers however the $\sin(\frac1{n^2})(\sin(n))^3$ is sometimes negative so can't use the comparision.

**Fourthly**, I have tried limit comparision with previous kind expressions as follows:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin(\frac1{n^2})(\sin(n))^3}{1/n^3}$$ which is indeterminate

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin(\frac1{n^2})(\sin(n))^3}{1/n^2}$$ which is again indeterminate

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sin(\frac1{n^2})(\sin(n))^3}{1/n^k}=0$$ if $0<k<2$

**Lastly**, I tried integral test but integral test is as hard as the problem itself.

**Any hint, solution would be appreciated.**

Comment: You can use similar idea as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197989/absolute-convergence-of-sinn-n2

Comment: Since $|\sin(1/n^2)\sin(n)^3 | \le |\sin(1/n^2)| \le 1/n^2$, the series converges absolutely, so it converges.

Comment: I cannot belıeve ıt, thought that was not absolutely convergent, thats why tried everything else

Comment: my brain really hurts

Comment: We can make the joke here, that doing math is so great because it feels sooooo good when you stop? :) Just kidding, but, well, there _is_ an element of truth to that. :) Even though I'm not as young as I once was, mathematical issues still plague me, and keep me awake at night, etc. :)